# Permutation Of String of length n with A B C

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

So I have to count the number of words of length N can be made with alphabets A B and C. (repetition allowed)

But condition is A's should not be together B'S should not be together.
and at-most m C's are allowed.

e.g For words of length n=2 and m=1 (c is allowed only 1 time) the following are allowed:

AB AC BA BC CA CB
Not allowed are AA BB CC (CC is not allowed because atmost 1 C is allowed).

Can anyone please help

Comment: Do you mean at most $m$ C's in total or at most $m$ C's in a row ?

Comment: like for every word only m C's are allowed

Comment: @codesandguns did you find any solution to do this? please help.

Answer (score 0):

The $C$s break the string into runs of $AB$s.  Each run has two choices because it can start with $A$ or $B$, then all the other letters are fixed.  I don't see an easy way to catalog them, but if $n=7,m=2$ you can have one run of $AB$, which happens if there are no $C$'s (one possibility), one $C$ at the end (two possibilities), or two $C$'s at the ends (three possibilities) for a total of $12$.  You can have two runs of $AB$ if there is one $C$ in the middle (five possibilities), one $C$ at the end and one in the middle (eight possibilities), or two $C$'s together in the middle (four possibilities) for a total of $48$.  You can have three runs of $AB$ if the two $C$'s are in the middle and separated (six possibilities) for $48$ total.  The grand total is then $108$

Comment: Thanks for the help. But what I'm looking for is a generic formula. Any help ?

Comment: No, if I had one I would have posted it.